# adding a colon to an input string

Tags: c#

I have 10 buttons inputting the numbers 0 to 9 into a string called input using the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBoxTimer.Text = "";
    input += "1";
    this.textBoxTimer.Text += input;
}
```

how would i get this so a colon is added after the second digit is added? (the centre of a four digit string)
I tried using the code:

```
output = input.Insert(2, ":");  
this.textBoxTimer.Text += output;
```

however this just returned an error of "unhandled exception has occurred in your application. Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: startIndex" when the button is pressed as the programme is running

Comment: Check the length of the input variable. If it is bigger than 0 add first the colon then the number

Comment: What kind of error did it "return"?

Comment: Tried changing the code to: 
            this.textBoxTimer.Text = "";
            output = input.Insert(2, ":");
            output += "1";
            this.textBoxTimer.Text += output;
presuming this is what you meant steve but this still did not work?

Comment: Assuming you're always going to be putting the colon after the last entered number, you should look at using the string's length as a start index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have an event handler method for each of the 10 buttons, right? In each of the event handlers, after these lines of code:

```
this.textBoxTimer.Text = "";
input += "1";
```

You can check whether `input` reached a length of `2`:

```
if (input.Length == 2) {

}
```

If it did, add a colon:

```
input += ":";
```

Then you can set the text to be `input`:

```
this.textBoxTimer.Text += input;
```